# Python Selenium 3X switch to frame does not work, but 2.53.6 is able to work

Tags: python, selenium

I use switch to frame element for "python selenium 2.53.6 , firefox 47" is working, but selenium 3.11 does not work.

python selenium 3.11 , firefox 61 (does not work) -

```
self.driver.switch_to.frame("topframe")
```

selenium 2.53.6 is able to work.
python selenium 2.53.6 , firefox 47 -

```
self.driver.switch_to.frame("topframe")
```

Comment: What exception you are getting?

Comment: Update the question with the relevant HTML and the error stack trace